# image link alignment issues when trying to align right

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, alignment

I can't figure out how to align these image links properly. My current ones look like this (i just used `align="right"` in the link):

[image: current links]

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

[image: what they should look like]

HTML:

```html
<a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php">
  <img src="webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png"; alt="Valid HTML5" align="right" />
</a>
<br /> 
<a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php">
  <img src="webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png"; alt="Valid CSS" align="right" /></a>
```

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png" alt="Valid HTML5" align="right" /></a><br />
   <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png" alt="Valid CSS" align="right" /></a>

Answer (score 1):

You can try vertical-align instead of align

```html
<a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php"><img src="webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-html.png"; alt="Valid HTML5" vertical-align="top" /></a><br />

<a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"><img src="webster.cs.washington.edu/images/w3c-css.png"; alt="Valid CSS" vertical-align="center" /></a>
```

Here the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z33xsh1s/)

Here the more reference on [**Vertical-align**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this.

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
img{
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
img:first-child{
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="" align="right">
  <a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php">
    <img src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/bart_roll_eyes.gif" alt="Valid HTML5" />
  </a>
  <a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php">
    <img src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/bart_roll_eyes.gif" alt="Valid CSS" />
  </a>
</div>
```

If you want an inline code use this.

```html
<div class="" align="right">
  <a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-html.php" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <img src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/bart_roll_eyes.gif" alt="Valid HTML5" style="display:block;border:1px solid #333;">
  </a>
  <br>
  <a href="webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php">
    <img src="http://www.avatarsdb.com/avatars/bart_roll_eyes.gif" alt="Valid CSS" style="display:block;border:1px solid #333;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: the only thing is I can't use magic numbers like that for the margin